# Get selected button value from the UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

From the array I am creating button with the array values inside each button, Here I want to place a radio button before each button. while clicking the radio button i want to get it selected or not. In the below code I can display the button and the radio button image but cannot get the selected button value. How can i get the radio button selected or not for each button

```
//My Array
labelArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three",@"four",@"five",@"six", nil];

//Creating button with placing a radio button image inside
-(void) createbutton:(CGRect) frame {
    CGFloat xCoordinate = frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat yCoordinate = frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat buttonHeight = frame.size.height;
    CGFloat buttonWidth = frame.size.width;
    CGFloat gapBetweenTwoButton = 2;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < [labelArrays count]; counter++) {
           button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
           button =[UIColor clearcolor];
           [button setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoordinate,yCoordinate, 100, 40)];  
           NSString* titre = [labelArrays objectAtIndex:counter];
           [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,0);
           [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",titre] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
           [self. button addTarget: self action: @selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           [self addSubview: button];

           if((counter+1)%3 == 0) {
              xCoordinate = 0;
              yCoordinate = yCoordinate + buttonHeight + gapBetweenTwobutton;
              xCoordinate = xCoordinate + buttonWidth + gapBetweenTwoLabels;
           }
   }

//my frame
[self createbutton:CGRectMake(32,20,220,40)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to get selected button value by using its tag value. See here and try below code.

Put these line in `viewDidLoad()`

```
labelArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six", nil];
[self createButtons];
```

And then define these methods.

```
- (void)createButtons
{
    int x = 30, y = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i<labelArrays.count; i++)
    {
        UIButton *btnImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnImage.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 40);
        btnImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        btnImage.tag = 700+i;
        [btnImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_unselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnImage.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
        [btnImage setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [labelArrays objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnImage addTarget: self action: @selector(changeValue:)forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.view addSubview:btnImage];

        if ((i+1)%2 == 0)
        {
            x = 30;
            y = y+btnImage.frame.size.height+10;
        }
        else
        {
            x = x+btnImage.frame.size.width+30;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)changeValue:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag];

    if (btn.selected == TRUE)
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_unselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.selected = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_select.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.selected = TRUE;
        NSLog(@"%@", btn.titleLabel.text);
    }
}
```